# Are there good example Flex project with well written unit tests?

Tags: apache-flex, unit-testing, tdd

My team is willing to start to write unit tests of our code (we will try even TDD).

Are there some good example Flex projects with well written unit tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AS3Commons and Spring ActionScript projects have a fairly elaborate set of unit tests:

- http://www.as3commons.org/
- http://www.springactionscript.org